# Jquery on Hash Change and browser back button.

Tags: jquery, browser, window

I have  a series of tabs that hide and how content. I've appened a url of #1 #2 etc. In other words, when someone clicks a tab it adds it to the url and then uses the onhashaschanged. here is the code.

```
jQuery( ".slidelinks li" ).click(function() {


  var identify=jQuery( ".slidelinks li" ).index( this );
 window.location = "#" + identify ;

if ("onhashchange" in window) {
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li " ).addClass('active');

    jQuery( ".slidelinks li " ).removeClass('active');
jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').eq(identify).removeClass("hide");
    jQuery( ".slidelinks li " ).eq(identify).addClass('active');
}


});
```

I understand that this is connected to click, but I am trying to figure out how to get the tabs to show when the back button or forward is used. I've tried to use the onhaschange outside of the click just to detect and see if anything happens on backbutton but nothing happens. My question is how can I run the onhaschange function if the backbutton is use from say mydomain.com/page/#3  back to mydomain.com/page/#2

Answer (score 0):

Ok if anyone is wondering I think it's figured out. 
I used this plugin 
https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange

and changed to the code to have the following.

```
jQuery(function(){

  // Bind the event.
  jQuery(window).hashchange( function(){
var locationminushas=location.hash.substring(1);

      jQuery( ".slidelinks li " ).addClass('active');

    jQuery( ".slidelinks li " ).removeClass('active');
jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').addClass("hide");
jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').eq(locationminushas).removeClass("hide");
    jQuery( ".slidelinks li " ).eq(locationminushas).addClass('active');
  })

  // Trigger the event (useful on page load).
  jQuery(window).hashchange();

});
```